# EF6: SelectMany as left join with runtime projection using AutoMapper?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to simplify some Entity Framework code which projects from "Users" and then LEFT JOINs various other tables to it, depending on the query.  One of these queries looks at all Users and includes data that indicates what Program (1 or 0) they participate in, and returns the combined data in a UserProgram object.  They are related by email address, not by a foreign key.   It currently looks like this:

```
public class User 
{
   public virtual int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual String Email {get; set;}
   //...
}

public class Programmember
{    
   public virtual int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual int Programid {get; set;}
   public virtual String Email {get; set;}
   //...
}

public IEnumerable<UserProgram> GetUsersWithProgram(int programid)
{
    IQueryable<User> userQueryable = ...
    var query = userQueryable
        .SelectMany(
            user=> ctx.ProgramMembers.Where(
                program => program.Email == user.Email
                    && program.programid == programid)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()), // LEFT JOIN                
                (user,program) => 
                     new UserProgram {
                          Email = user.Email,
                          Programname = program.Name
                          // lots of other fields...
                     }
```

I want to replace the call to "new UserProgram" with AutoMapper to combine the two objects into one "DTO" object, but I don't see if it's possible.  The solution that I've seen is to use `.Project().To<UserProgram>()` to construct a SELECT, but requires that I can navigate between Users and Programs.  (I didn't set it up to navigate from Users to Programs because the relationship between the two tables is somewhat ad-hoc and not related by a foreign key.)

Is there a way to do this without explicitly new-ing a UserProgram object?  Obviously, I can't call Mapper.Map directly, since this will not map to a Linq-to-Entities query.

Comment: I think my approach to this was wrong.  Instead of using AutoMapper to project multiple objects, a better way to do this is to project this using Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

could you try it:

```
var query =     from c in userQueryable
                join program in ctx.ProgramMembers.Where(p=> p.programid == programid) ON c.Email    equals program.Email into joined
                from program in joined.DefaultOrEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    Email = c.Email,
                    ProgramName = program == null ? "(null)" : program.Name 
                };
```

or you can use ToLookUp();

```
var ctx_lookUp = ctx.ProgramMembers.Where(p=>p.programid == programid).ToLookup(item => item.Email);

var query = from c in userQueryable
            select new
            {
               Email = c.Email,
               programName = ctx_lookup[c.Email].SingleOrDefault("(null)").Select(item=>item.Name)
            };

SingleOrDefault() - return one object or 0, if your database will have more that 1, then you will get exception :-)
```

**Please test it, i don't have now a VS and i'm writing it without debugger. Please answer if a something will not work.**

Comment: Thanks, but I think that using ToLookup won't work because it can't be mapped to a SQL query.  (i.e. "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ... get_Item(System.String)")  I'm not sure how I could replace the "new" in the first solution with an AutoMapper projection---it looks equivalent to what I already have....